# How to change the default text shown when no option is selected?

Tags: react-select

By default when the react-select is rendered i see "Select..." on the component. I want to see "Search ...".

Looking at the [docs](https://react-select.com/props), I am assuming I need to use the noOptionsMessage prop, which is documented as:

```
noOptionsMessage function = () => undefined
Text to display when there are no options

({
inputValue string required
}) => One of<
react.Node,
null
>
```

I did not really understand that bit of the docs. E.g. this prop seems to be a function. So, I have been trying variations including following without success:

```
<AsyncSelect
   cacheOptions
   defaultOptions={[]}
   loadOptions={handleLoadOptions}
   onChange={handleChange}
   noOptionsMessage={()=> "Search..."}
/>
```

So, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add placeholder to the AsyncSelect.

```
    <AsyncSelect
   cacheOptions
   defaultOptions={[]}
   loadOptions={handleLoadOptions}
   onChange={handleChange}
   placeholder='Search...'
/>
```

Common props you may want to specify include:

autoFocus - focus the control when it mounts
className - apply a className to the control
classNamePrefix - apply classNames to inner elements with the given prefix
isDisabled - disable the control
isMulti - allow the user to select multiple values
isSearchable - allow the user to search for matching options
name - generate an HTML input with this name, containing the current value
onChange - subscribe to change events
options - specify the options the user can select from
**placeholder - change the text displayed when no option is selected**
value - control the current value